# Infinitely differentiable of Fourier solution to heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, heat-equation

Given $f (x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}e^{-n^2t}\phi_{n}(x)$ with $\phi_{n}(x) =\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin(nx)$ and $a_n = \int_{0}^{\pi} f_0(x)\phi_{n}(x)dx$ is the Fourier solution to the heat equation $f_t - f_{xx} = 0$ on $(0,\pi)$ with Dirichlet condition $f(0,t) = f(\pi, t) = 0$ and initial condition $f(x,0) = f_{0}(x)$. In addition, assume $|a_{n}|\leq M$ for all $n$.

**Question:** Prove that $f(x,t)$ is $C^{\infty}$ in $x$ for each $t > 0$.

**My attempt:** I was able to show that at each $t = t_0$ ($t_0$ is fixed), $f(x,t_0)$ converges uniformly in $x$, thus $f(x,t)$ is $C^0$. But when I differentiate with respect to $x$, I got $f_x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}e^{-n^2t_0}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\ n\cos(nx)$. But I can't see how to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\cos(nx) e^{-n^2t_0}$ converges, as the extra term $n$ causes me big trouble in bounding this series by a convergent series to apply the Weirstrass M-test. The more I differentiate, the higher degree of the term $n$ I would get.

Can anyone please help prove the later case (1st and 2nd derivative) to show that $f(x,t_0)$ is $C^{1}$ and $C^{2}$ in $x$?

Comment: If $t_0>0$, you have an exponential decay in your Fourier series.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For any fixed $t_0>0$, the exponential decay induced by $e^{-n^2 t_0}$ eats up any polynomial weight that arises from differentiation (of any order) in $x$. This can be expressed formally by an inequality such as the following:
$$\lvert n^k e^{-n^2 t_0}\rvert\le C_{t_0, k}\,e^{-n^2 \frac{t_0}2}. $$
In particular, the series for $\partial^k_x f$ converges uniformly in $x$ for any $k$.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! But can you kindly show how to obtain $C_{t_0,k}$? Because with this inequality, the problem is completely solved!!

Comment: You can show that the function $y>0 \mapsto y^k e^{-t_0(y^2-y)}$ is bounded, for example. But that inequality is just an example and I did not write it with much care. The better bound $\lvert n^k e^{-n^2 t_0}\rvert \le C_{t_0, k} e^{-\frac{t_0}2 n^2}$ is probably even easier to establish.

Comment: (edited to include the easier-to-prove bound)

Comment: I still don't see why:( can you be more detailed about how to show $|n^{k}e^{-n^2\frac{t_{0}}{2}}|$ is bounded by something involving $t_0$ and $k$ for $n\in Z^{+}$ and $t_0 > 0$ only?

Comment: As I said, switch to the continuous variable $y\ge 0$. Then prove that $y^k e^{-\frac{t_0}2 y^2}$ is bounded on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: I worked it out, and obtained the result $C = max(e^{\frac{-k}{2}}(\sqrt{\frac{k}{t_0}})^k, e^{\frac{-t_0}{2}})$ on $[1,\infty]$ rather than $[0,\infty]$. The critical point of the function you mentioned above is  $y = \sqrt{\frac{k}{t_0}}$. Can you help confirm if this is correct?

Comment: The reason I consider $[1,\infty]$ was because $y$ should be positive integers, as we have discrete case, but we purposefully proved it for continuous case since the result doesn't change, and I already showed it's true for the case $k=0$, so I think that's fine?

Comment: I think it's OK. A quicker way would be to observe that $y^ke^{-\frac{t_0}2 y^2}$ is continuous on $[1, \infty)$ and has a finite limit as $y\to \infty$. Therefore it must be bounded. Of course, this approach does not give the explicit constant, which can sometimes be useful. Good work

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. It's all your credit:)

Comment: @Downvoter: if you have problems with this answer, and care to explain what those problems are, I can try to fix them.

Comment: I'm sorry for your incidence, but you shouldn't really mind about the upvote/downvote (I know how you feel, but it isn't THAT important, is it?) By the way, can you please help review my solution for this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448419/nonnegative-solution-of-a-pde-with-zeroth-order-term

Comment: I don't care about the down vote, I was just wondering whether the answer was considered wrong by someone, and why. (And unfortunately I have no time to check your other post now, good luck)

Comment: I don't think yours is wrong...And no, you can check it anytime when u're free... No need to do it right away, but please help if u can.