# Nonnegative solution of a PDE with zeroth order term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Given the PDE, $x_t - \triangle x + c(m,t)x = 0$, on a bounded domain $\omega$ where $c(m,t)$ is a smooth function (bounded but can be negative). Show that if $x_{0}(m) = x(m,0)\geq 0$, then $x(m,t)\geq 0$ for every $x\in \omega$ and $t > 0$.

**My attempt:** We consider the transformation $v(m,t)=e^{\lambda\ t} x(m,t)$, so after doing some algebraic manipulation, we can rewrite the PDE:

$v_t - \triangle v + c(m,t)v = e^{\lambda t}[x_t(1-2\lambda) - \triangle x + x(-\lambda^{2} + c(m,t)] = 0$

$\Leftrightarrow x_t - \frac{\triangle x}{1-2\lambda} + x(\frac{-\lambda^{2} + \lambda + c(m,t)}{1-2\lambda}) = 0$ (assume $\lambda \neq \frac{1}{2}$)

Now, the main idea is to choose $\lambda$ such that the term  $\frac{-\lambda^{2} + \lambda + c(m,t)}{1-2\lambda}\geq 0$. Since $c(m,t)$ is bounded, such $\lambda$ exists (I examined each case to find the value of $\lambda$ based on whether $\min\ (\max\ c(m,t), 1) = \max\ c(m,t)$ or $1$). Thus, by applying the weak maximum principle for the problem $x_t - \triangle x + c(m,t) x = 0$ with $c(m,t)\geq 0$, we get: $\min{x}\geq \max\ (x_{0}^{-})$ where $x_0^{-}$ denotes the negative parts of $x_0$. Since $x_0\geq 0$ by the given assumption, $\min\ (x)\geq \max\ (x_0^{-}) \geq 0$. Thus $x(m,t)\geq 0$ for every $x\in \omega$ and $t > 0$ (Q.E.D)

**Concern about the solution above:** In the case above, the coefficient of $\triangle x$ is not $-1$, but $\frac{-1}{1-2\lambda}$, but I think the conclusion is the same? Someone please corrects me if I'm wrong on this, as the final conclusion would be incorrect if this premise is not true.

Comment: Nobody minds reviewing my solution above, or at least helping me with my own concern about my solution?

Comment: It should be fine supposing $\frac{-1}{1-2\lambda}<0$, since the problem is still uniformly parabolic. So your assumption should be $\lambda<\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I agree with @ellya, of course. The condition $-1/(1-2\lambda)<0$ is essential, not only for the maximum principle, but also for the well-posedness of the equation. It is better that it is fulfilled.

Comment: P.S.: It would be nice to specify the boundary conditions that you are assuming. (And why do you use the letter $m$ to denote a spatial point? ;-) )

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: the boundary condition is Dirichlet condition, $x = 0$ on $\partial \omega\times [0,T]$. Btw, you meant if I have $v_t + \triangle v + c(m,t)v = 0$ with $c(m,t)\geq 0$, then the weak maximum principle cannot apply, and the problem is ill-posed? Why is that the case? And $m$ is just my habit:p

Comment: @ellya: so you meant if the problem is not uniformly parabolic, then the weak maximum principle cannot be applied? Can you explain the reason why?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro & ellya: based on your comments, you seem to agree that the weak maximum principle can apply to $v_t - k\triangle v + c(m,t)v = 0$ as long as $k > 0$ and $c(m,t)\geq 0$?

Comment: @ellya: can you help answer my question in the comment above?

Comment: have a look at Evans PDE chapter 7 - linear parabolic equations of second order

Comment: I took a look at that chapter already... but so far, if $c(m,t) < 0$, I don't think I can have a way to choose $\lambda$ such that $\frac{-1}{1-2\lambda} < 0$ AND $\frac{c(m,t)-\lambda^2}{1-2\lambda} > 0$. I need these two conditions to use the result mentioned in my previous comments.

Comment: @ellya: Nevermind:( I realized I made a computational mistake. The last term should be $\frac{c(m,t) - \lambda^2 + lambda}{1-2\lambda}$. Now, for the case $c(m,t) < 0$, I only need to choose $\lambda =  max c(m,t)$, which would  satisfy BOTH conditions! By using the result above, I got the conclusion. Is this correct?